i can't send uploaded files from react to express, literally express can't see it
Hello, i have problem about files, for exact, my backend can't read uploaded files, which is from front input type.
const filesRef = useRef(null);

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(fileUpload({ useTempFiles: true }));

 <form
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          method="POST"
          encType="multipart/form-data"
        >
 </form>

I have enctype=multipart/form-data in form instead of axios headers
i have formData and i'm looping over and get uploaded files dynamically.

But if i pass headers content type multipart/form-data in axios headers, i can't log anything on backend side.

const formData = new FormData();
    const files = filesRef.current;
    for (let i = 0; i < files.files.length; i++) {
      formData.append("files", files.files[i]);
    }
    try {



      const resImage = await baseURL
        .post("/products/uploadImage", {
          formData,
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res));
      // console.log(resImage);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

Then i import multer and do configs:
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "../uploads");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log(file);
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
    );
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

i have uploadImages route where i pass multer middleware:
I know that upload.array("files") must be the same as formData.append("files")
router.post(
  "/uploadImage",
  [authenticateUser, upload.array("files")],
  uploadImage
);

But on backend when i loggin in console req.body shows formData: {} - empty object and req.files - undefined
const uploadImage = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body); - ** formData: {} empty object**
  console.log(req.files); - **undefined**
  const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    req.files.images.tempFilePath,
    {
      use_filename: true,
      folder: "E-Commerce",
    }
  );
  fs.unlinkSync(req.files.images.tempFilePath);
  res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ src: result.secure_url });
};

   <input
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          alt="upload image"
          className="product-images-input"
          name="files"
          id="files"
          multiple
          hidden
          ref={filesRef}
        />

version is: "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1"
I can't get it what i do wrong, pretend everything is ok but i think multer doesn't work.
